# Flutter: Some images are displayed sideways(rotated 90 degrees)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

On iOS some photos are displayed sideways (i.e rotated 90 degrees). This seems to affect some photos randomly but consistently(i.e photos that are displayed sideways are always displayed sideways) and happens more often with Live Photos. I use image_picker (https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to select the images. The problem persists irrespective of the widget used to display the photo.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: Check [this](https://roszkowski.dev/2020/rotate-image-from-camera-in-flutter/) out!

Comment: @DrSatan1 I already tried that. Did not work. Thanks

Comment: Ok cool. Can you share what was wrong with that solution?
Because end of the day it seems the image is rotated by the camera, and the solution would be to determine the true rotation and rotate it accordingly.

Comment: @DrSatan1 It incorrectly identified images that didn't need rotation as needing rotation and thus rotated them. It also ignored some photos that were giving me issues. It was also quite slow to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [this article](https://roszkowski.dev/2020/rotate-image-from-camera-in-flutter/) as the starting point, I was able to fix it by analyzing different images where rotation happens to tease out a pattern. This may be very specific to my case but it works for me at this point.

```
Future<void> applyRotationFix(String originalPath) async {
  try {
    Map<String, IfdTag> data = await readExifFromFile(File(originalPath));
    print(data);

    int length = int.parse(data['EXIF ExifImageLength'].toString());
    int width = int.parse(data['EXIF ExifImageWidth'].toString());
    String orientation = data['Image Orientation'].toString();

    if (length != null && width != null && orientation != null) {
      if (length > width) {
        if (orientation.contains('Rotated 90 CW')) {
          img.Image original =
              img.decodeImage(File(originalPath).readAsBytesSync());
          img.Image fixed = img.copyRotate(original, -90);
          File(originalPath).writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(fixed));
        } else if (orientation.contains('Rotated 180 CW')) {
          img.Image original =
              img.decodeImage(File(originalPath).readAsBytesSync());
          img.Image fixed = img.copyRotate(original, -180);
          File(originalPath).writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(fixed));
        } else if (orientation.contains('Rotated 270 CW')) {
          img.Image original =
              img.decodeImage(File(originalPath).readAsBytesSync());
          img.Image fixed = img.copyRotate(original, -270);
          File(originalPath).writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(fixed));
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```